# multiple property values in has clause of gremlin

Tags: neo4j, gremlin

Can I pass multiple properties with values inside has clause of gremlin queries like :

```
g.V.has(['country','AUS'],['country','USA'])
```

Comment: g.V.has('country','AUS','USA') ...is it the right syntax ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> g.V.has('age',T.in,[29,32])               
==>v[1]
==>v[4]
```

Comment: am using gremlin 1.5 . also import ..import com.tinkerpop.gremlin.Tokens.T.. but it says ==> No such property: in for class: com.tinkerpop.gremlin.Tokens$T

Comment: What version of Gremlin are you using?  That syntax was for 2.4.0.

Comment: am using gremlin 1.5 in neo4j 1.9.2

Comment: can you upgrade?  i don't know if there is a nice option for "multiple property values" otherwise.  assuming `country` is a non-indexed property and you can survive a scan, you could put your property values in a list and then do `g.V.filter{values.contains(it)}`.

Comment: yes it'working on upper version. actually has is faster then filter. so  i thought to use this ..but problem is already older version is there. so trying to do that with the same. thanx anyways.:)