# Gremlin: T.in operator error with has() filter in Titan 0.3.2

Tags: gremlin, titan, rexster

I'm having trouble using the T.in operator with has() filter in Titan 0.3.2

The following Gremlin query...:

```
g.V("type", "articles").out("has_tag").has("name", T.in, ["foobar"])
```

... yields the following error in Titan console:

```
No such property: in for class: com.tinkerpop.gremlin.Tokens$T
```

Somehow related to this SO question : [multiple property values in has clause of gremlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18797049/multiple-property-values-in-has-clause-of-gremlin) (same question, but related to Neo4J).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Titan 0.3.2 does not support TinkerPop 2.4.0 (it supports 2.3.0).  I think you can expect that to be available in the soon to be release Titan 0.4.0.

In Titan 0.3.2 I think you would have to do:

```
g.V.filter{values.contains(it)}
```

Where `values` is your list of things to match on.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I indeed thought that TinkerPop 2.3.0 supported T.in with has() filter. I should/could have double checked that. Appreciate your help!